# Integrating Pusher to a simple php web app

Tags: php, web-applications, pusher

Hello stackoverflow community, I am learning how to implement Pusher API http://pusher.com into this simple web chat app. I was following a video tutorial and did every step correctly, but when I try to send a msg, it will be displayed correctly on my web browser, but will not be displayed or refreshed on another web browser. I will add my 2 php files, they are short.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Pusher Messenger</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://js.pusher.com/3.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
        //Pusher.logToConsole = true;

        var pusher = new Pusher('your pusher key here', {
          encrypted: true
        });

        var channel = pusher.subscribe('channel_pusher');
        channel.bind('new_message', function(response){
          $('#sent_messages').append('<li>' + response.message + '</li>');
        });

        $(function(){
            $('form').submit(function(){
                $.post('ajax.php', { msj : $('#input_mensaje').val() }, function(response){
                    //funcion de callback
                    $('#sent_messages').append('<li>' + response.message + '</li>');
                }, 'json');

                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" methor="post">
            <input type="text" id="input_mensaje" />
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" />
        </form>

        <ul id="sent_messages">
            <!-- Sent messages will be shown here -->
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And this is my ajax.php file:

```
<?php
    require('lib/Pusher.php');

    $options = array(
        'encrypted' => true
    );

    $message = $_POST['msj'];

    $pusher = new Pusher(
        'code provided by pusher',
        'code provided by pusher',
        'code provided by pusher',
        $options
      );

    $pusher->trigger(
        'channel_pusher',
        'new_message',
        array('message' => $message)
    );

    echo json_encode(array('message' => $message));
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Sounds like you should specify in which browser this works for you correctly and in which one it doesn't. Or is it any other browser, including same browser on another PC and another browser on your PC?

Comment: yes, you are right, it won't refresh on any web browser, the main problem is that it is not showing real time messages. For example: I write "Hello", and it will display it on my web browser, but if I have another web browser beside it, there will be no messages displayed.

Comment: Can i get some help?

Comment: I'd recommend to add the link to the tutorial you used here. Since you don't have enough reputation to add a second link to your post, I'll update it. I'm not familiar with Pusher, but a simple note would be the following. For multiple people to communicate, you PHP should a) recieve new messages, b) store them somewhere c) regularly check for new messages in the store and send them to the front-end (the word "push" basicaly means that). I can see recieving, I'm not sure about storing (does this `$pusher->trigger` part do that?) and I can't see sending at all..

Comment: So it is a simple app to learn how to integrate the pusher API, it won't store the messages anywhere, I can give you the link to the tutorial, it is in spanish tho... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75Wufnf2aRk Also... you need to have the Pusher library in your server, you can get it from github, just type Pusher library and you will get it, it is a single php file :D

Comment: Wait, if it doesn't store the messages, how do you expect it to implement a chat? If one person opens a php script and another one does, there's no way those script processes know about each other, except if they either store data to disk or communicate to another software that works continously and "knows" about both instances, is there?

Comment: you are right, and that is what pusher does, watch the video, ignore the voice because it is in spanish, but he never access a data base, he just implements pusher library into his code and at the end he shows the chat between 2 browsers updating instantly and showing new messages (also, it is displaying in a <li></li> maybe that is the way he saves the mssages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just tested your code with my own app key and it seems to work fine.
I did notice, however, that while you included your app key and secret in the ajax.php you quoted (which should normally be avoided), your HTML only contains

```
var pusher = new Pusher('your pusher key here',
```

Please make sure to provide the app key in both files so that both can actually communicate with Pusher.

Another thing to note is that your ajax.php currently passes a message submitted from the page both to Pusher and also back to the page itself.
The upshot of this is that the page that submitted the message will in fact append it twice, once from the response returned by ajax.php and once upon the new_message event being received from Pusher.
This may or may not be what you had in mind.

Comment: hahahaha, sorry, here is the thing, I removed my app key from the pusher object to not make my key public in this forum, but I forgot to remove it on the ajax file, anyways.. it is a simple web app so I don't care, I can request a new one. So for the second thing you mentioned, it does repeat twice because the function is two times, to avoid that you need to add a parameter called socket_id : pusher.connection.socket_id; and into ajax trigger function as well, but I tried it and it doesn't work. Also, I am running WAMP, it may have something to do with my web browser that doesn't make it work?